# How to make km2 or m2 in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

In HTML, there is the `<sup>...</sup>` tag to get something like

```
km2
```

How would one do that in react native?

Comment: Just literally write km² or m²? You don't need markup for that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ah, I have not even tried that because I thought I need markup...